# I am trying to convert mp4 file into text using python but i am getting this error

Tags: python, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook

i am doing this in jupyter notebook and the video is placed in the same folder which is mp4 file i want to convert nanavi.mp4 file into text by recognizing what is being said inside the video but i am getting this error

enter code here

```
import speech_recognition as sr

import os

import pyaudio

command2mp3 = 'ffmpeg -i nanavi.mp4 nanavi.mp3'

command2wav = 'ffmpeg -i nanavi.mp3 nanavi.wav'

os.system(command2mp3)

os.system(command2wav)

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile("nanavi.wav") as source:

    audio = r.record(source, duration=10)

    print(r.recognize_google(audio))

**ERROR**
```

*the file is already placed in the folder of the ipynb file*

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-19-9f97c7524cb8> in <module>

----> 1 with sr.AudioFile("nanavi.wav") as source:

      2     audio = r.record(source, duration=10)

      3     print(r.recognize_google(audio))


C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py in __enter__(self)

    201         try:
    202             # attempt to read the file as WAV
--> 203             self.audio_reader = wave.open(self.filename_or_fileobject, "rb")
    204             self.little_endian = True  # RIFF WAV is a little-endian format (most ``audioop`` operations assume that the frames are stored in little-endian form)
    205         except (wave.Error, EOFError):

C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\wave.py in open(f, mode)
    508             mode = 'rb'
    509     if mode in ('r', 'rb'):
--> 510         return Wave_read(f)
    511     elif mode in ('w', 'wb'):
    512         return Wave_write(f)

C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\wave.py in __init__(self, f)
    158         self._i_opened_the_file = None
    159         if isinstance(f, str):
--> 160             f = builtins.open(f, 'rb')
    161             self._i_opened_the_file = f
    162         # else, assume it is an open file object already

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nanavi.wav'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing flac by running the command

```
sudo apt-get install flac
```

This is a common codec related issue and installing flac will solve it.

Comment: flac isn't mentioned anywhere in the question.

Comment: i am doing it in windows and i think there is some problem with ffmpeg